# How can I customization local notification in Ionic 3 for every 3 days local notification for iOS & Android?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, localnotification

I am creating a simple local notification for Android & iOS both.
Technology using ionic 3 frameworks it's working fine with every second, minute, hour, day, week, month & year but I need local notification for every 3 days so what can I do for that?

Please help me.

I am using plugin of ionic is

> [ionic cordova plugin add de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/local-notifications/)

Thanks!

Regards,
Karmdip Joshi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution for it.

I am updating the cordova plugin and please refer my [github](https://github.com/karmdip/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/tree/master) url.

Comment: Will it work every day specific time? Example: every day 10 am,  02 pm, 05 pm

Comment: Yes, it will work but if you find anything plz let me know about it then I fix it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no option to change any customization in ionic local notification plugin. If you want to change any customization then you have to go with native code. Because currently there are few options available.

But It might be possible customization in next version.

Comment: Okay Kiran, I can try to customization if I have any query so I am asking to you about this.